# PISO Shift Register using 74LS166

Tags: digital-logic, shift-register, register

I'been doing a PISO shift register using a 74LS166, but I get no results, I don't know what is happening. Here is the top view and my approach.

In my approach:

- **BLUE wire** = Clear
- **PURPLE(MARRON)** = Clock Pulse
- **YELLOW** = Clock Inhibit
- **GREEN** = Shift/Load

As you guys can see there is a space in the first place. There I have to put the serial input but i don't where I have to connect it.

Hope you can help me to make it works.
Thanks  in advance.

[image]

[image: My approach]

Comment: I guess nobody will know what do you want.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I want to implement a PISO swift register, the second picture is what I have done, but it doesn't work. I am confused with the serial input. I don't know what kind a signal (LOW or HIGH) it has to have.

Comment: I depends on what you want to get after you have shifted the whole 8 bits, if you want 9th bit to be L then it has to be L, if you want H, then let it be H.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Ok, I already put in L. Now, to load the 8 bits on the parallel input.  What I have to do with the clock and the clock inhibit??. When I push the clock it seems that nothing happens.

Comment: that layout looks ok what switches and buttes are you switching inwhat order?

Comment: set SH/~LD  low, pulse CLK high, set SH_LD high, now you should see the data coming out when you pulse CLK.

Answer (score 1):

1. set clk inhibit L, set Clear H,
2. set parallel inputs.
3. switch shift/load to L
4. apply pulse to CLK
5. switch shift/load to H
6. apply pulses on CLK

Comment: Marko, thanks a lot, the LED is lighting. I'm so gratefull